# How can I run list_vms check as user (seems to be run as root)?

Tags: ansible

I have a check for existing VMs in ansible but it seems to be checking VMs as root and not as user.  I tried including become_user but this made no difference.

The play is as follows.

```
  - name: Check VMs
    virt:
      command: "list_vms"
    register: vms
    delegate_to: '{{ groups["RU"][play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) % groups["RU"]|length] }}'
```

The result is as follows.

```
TASK [Check VMs] ***************************************************************
ok: [test01 -> RU5]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [test01] => {
    "vms": {
        "changed": false,
        "list_vms": [
            "vagrant_network01",
            "vagrant_compute01",
            "Solaris11-virtio",
            "vagrant_control01",
            "vagrant_operator",
            "vagrant_control02",
            "vagrant_storage01",
            "Solaris11"
        ]
    }
}
```

Why does it return these?  I am not running as root.  The VM is created as my user etc. when I remove the check.

Answer (score 0):

virt commands run as root, maybe this can be changed?  I can work around by using shell as follows.

```
  - name: Check VMs
    #virt:
    #  command: "list_vms"
    shell: virsh list --all
    register: vms
    delegate_to: '{{ groups["RU"][play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) % groups["RU"]|length] }}'
```

Resulting in:

```
TASK [Check VMs] ***************************************************************
changed: [test01 -> RU5]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [test01] => {
    "vms": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "virsh list --all",
        "delta": "0:00:00.023960",
        "end": "2019-01-22 14:31:09.909886",
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2019-01-22 14:31:09.885926",
        "stderr": "",
        "stdout": "test01",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "test01"
        ],
        "warnings": []
    }
}
```

The conditional check would then be:

```
when: inventory_hostname not in vms.stdout
```

If someone can advise on how to use virt as user, I'd appreciate it.